# Unable to render html form template in class based views in django

Tags: django

I have an HTML page with a link to redirect to another HTML template which has a form. I have used the class based view in rendering it. But it simply does not load. 
My views.py look something like :

```
def startup(request):
    return render(request, 'main/startup.html')    

class AddStartup(CreateView):
    model = Startup
    template_name = 'startup_form.html'
    fields = ['startup_name', 'startup_product', 'startup_date', 'startup_sector', 'startup_team_size',
        'startup_desc', 'startup_team_condition', 'startup_team']
```

urls.py

```
# I have posted only the relevant code
url(r'startup/$', views.startup, name = 'startup'),
    url(r'startup/add-startup/$', views.AddStartup.as_view(), name = 'add-startup'),
```

My HTML page which has a link to navigate to the field is below

```
{% extends "main/base.html" %}
{%block content%}
pass<br>
<a 
    href = "{%url "main:add-startup"%}" target="_parent" method = "post">
    Add Startup
</a>
{%endblock%}
```

I am a bit confused in Class based views so that is why I choose to mix them. Help would be appriciated

Comment: Remove `target="_parent" method = "post"` from a tag

Comment: I did. Still not working

Comment: Use single quotes remove double `"{% url 'main:add-startup' %}"`

Comment: Does not work. I think the error is not with the link. I can see the url changing by clicking. But same page is displayed even when the url changes.

Comment: please kindly post also what the traceback is showing.

Comment: @Shift'NTab Its not showing anything. Just the page M currently on remains even when I click the link, even the url changes from '/startup/' to '/startup/' but the same page remains.

Comment: does the urls file has an `app_name=main`? did your already put a namespacing?

Comment: I did. Everything seems fine.